# CI function not working from external php script

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to run a CI controller > method from external php script.. that external php script sends some values using `curl`

```
$url = 'http://domain.com/ci_system/billing/success';

$fields = array(
    'ammount' => $extra[0]['ammount'],
    'email' => $extra[0]['email'],
    'cemail' => $extra[0]['cemail'],
    'rcode' => $completeResponse->getResponseCode(),
    'message' => $completeResponse->getResponseText()
);
$post = http_build_query($fields);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

above success function I have to send a email. `curl` sends all required data to success function but is is not working. when i manually trigger this function it works..

## controller > method

```
$this->cart->destroy();
$ord = array(
    'online' => 1
);
$this->Billing_model->updateOrder($ord, $this->session->userdata('data_o_i'));
//send email to the client
$this->load->library('email');
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('noreply@zxzxzxz.com', 'Dsd Retail New Order');
$this->email->to($this->input->post('omail@gmail.com'));

$this->email->subject('You have a new message for yor order');
$this->email->message($this->input->post('email'));
```

Comment: Is your success action accept post?

Comment: Could it be wrong spelling in amount variable?

Comment: yes, if I make 'echo' for above one of data it will show.. the thing is email function inside the success function not working. even i cant execute a database query.

Comment: Could you post your success action here?

Comment: I attached it with my question

Comment: $this->session->userdata('data_o_i')
You are using a session which does not exist when you are using curl. So your updateOrder should return a error and rest of the code should not work.

Comment: nop... I tested everything all variables fine. thing is they are not triggering it self. I m finding a way to trigger $this->cart->destroy();   and  $this->email->message($this->input->post('email'));

Comment: Try logging before and after 
$this->Billing_model->updateOrder($ord, $this->session->userdata('data_o_i')); and run it from curl and see if you can see both messages in your log file.

Comment: I just removed everything inside success function and put a redirect to my home controller. but not working.

Comment: Redirection will not work if it is called from curl. Add a log message like log_message('debug', 'before updateOrder'); and see if it is working after called from curl

Comment: in the success function i just put `echo "@payment_success"; `and it working but when I put `redirect('home');` it is not working.. Im calling this `success` function from external php script out side the application folder. but I directly call this function it is working.

Comment: I'm not sure if you need this CI action called from curl over a URL or external cli script outside of the application?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97177/discussion-between-pradeep-sanjaya-and-kanishka-b-kodithuwakku).

Answer (score 2):

First of all check if your action is working fine and give you expected behaviour if you call it from url.

I have following setup with ci3.

**Hosts**

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 ci3.local
```

**Apache sites-available**

```
cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/ci3.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin email@email.com
        ServerName ci3.local
    DocumentRoot /home/user/project/ci3

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ci3_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ci3_access.log combined

    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

    <Directory /home/user/project/ci3>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
    </Directory> 

</VirtualHost>
```

ci3/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

ci3/application/config/routes.php

```
$route['billing/success'] = 'billing/success';
```

ci3/application/controllers/Billing.php

```
<?php
class Billing extends CI_Controller {

    public function success()
    {
        log_message('debug', 'Billing.success');
        log_message('debug', $this->input->post('amount'));
    }
}
```

Now if I request http://ci3.local/billing/success from browser, it will log following output to my log file

```
DEBUG - 2015-12-07 08:47:34 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2015-12-07 08:47:34 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
DEBUG - 2015-12-07 08:47:34 --> Billing.success
DEBUG - 2015-12-07 08:47:34 --> 
DEBUG - 2015-12-07 08:47:34 --> Total execution time: 0.0019
```

**How do I call it from terminal and check if it is working?**

```
$ curl --data "amount=200" http://ci3.local/billing/success
```

Then I should see my log entries like below

```
DEBUG - 2015-12-07 08:49:38 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2015-12-07 08:49:38 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
DEBUG - 2015-12-07 08:49:38 --> Billing.success
DEBUG - 2015-12-07 08:49:38 --> 200
DEBUG - 2015-12-07 08:49:38 --> Total execution time: 0.0021
```

**How do I call this action from a CURL over http?**

ci3/curl.php

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => "http://ci3.local/billing/success",
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
        'amount' => '300'
    )
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Call curl.php from terminal

```
php5 curl.php
```

Then I should see my log entries like below

```
DEBUG - 2015-12-07 08:53:41 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2015-12-07 08:53:41 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
DEBUG - 2015-12-07 08:53:41 --> Billing.success
DEBUG - 2015-12-07 08:53:41 --> 300
DEBUG - 2015-12-07 08:53:41 --> Total execution time: 0.0021
```